# Calculating the summation $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n+1}}{n(n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

I need to find explicitly the following summation

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n+1}}{n(n+1)}, \quad 
H_{n}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$$

From Mathematica, I checked that the answer is $2$. The same result is [returned by WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%201%20to%20infty%20harmonic(n%2B1)%2F(n(n%2B1)).

A thought from afar:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{H_{n+1}}{n(n+1)}
&=H_{n+1}\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)\tag1\\
&=\color{#C00}{H_{n+1}}\color{#090}{(H_n-H_{n-1})}-H_{n+1}(H_{n+1}-H_n)\tag2\\
&=\color{#C00}{\frac1{n+1}}\color{#090}{\frac1n}+\color{#C00}{H_n}\color{#090}{(H_n-H_{n-1})}-H_{n+1}(H_{n+1}-H_n)\tag3\\
&=\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}+\frac{H_n}{n}-\frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1}\tag4\\
&=\frac{H_n+1}{n}-\frac{H_{n+1}+1}{n+1}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
What was done:
$(1)$: partial fractions
$(2)$: used $\frac1n=H_n-H_{n-1}$ and $\frac1{n+1}=H_{n+1}-H_n$
$(3)$: used $\color{#C00}{H_{n+1}=\frac1{n+1}+H_n}$ and $\color{#090}{\frac1n=H_n-H_{n-1}}$
$(4)$: partial fractions and $\frac1n=H_n-H_{n-1}$ and $\frac1{n+1}=H_{n+1}-H_n$
$(5)$: combined terms

Now this looks like Clement C's hint.

Comment: Did you try to see if it telescopes?

Comment: Start with 1/(n(n+1)) = 1/n - 1/(n+1) I would think.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $H_{n+2}-H_{n+1}=\frac{1}{n+2}$, hence summation by parts converts such series into an elementary (telescopic) one.

Comment: A question about the same series: [How to show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n+1}}{n(n+1)}=2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2685921)

Comment: Since the question was undeleted, perhaps it is worth adding also links to two posts on meta about this question: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-07-2018/28017#28017 and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today/30181#30181

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**(Big) hint:**

$$\frac{H_{n+1}}{n(n+1)}
= \frac{H_{n+1}}{n}-\frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1}
= \frac{1}{n(n+1)} + \frac{H_{n}}{n}-\frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1}$$
so that you can get a telescopic series: for any $N\geq 1$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{H_{n+1}}{n(n+1)} 
= \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n(n+1)}  + \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{H_{n}}{n}  - \sum_{n=2}^{N +1}\frac{H_{n}}{n}
$$

**Spoiler:**

> The value you should arrive at is $2$, which is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}  + 1$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n+1}}{n(n+1)}
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1k\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n+1}\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)
+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{(n+1)^2}\right)
+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac1k\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Now its simply summing telescoping series (three times).

Answer (score 2):

Noting that
$$\frac{1}{n(n + 1)} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + 1},$$
the sum may be rewritten as
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_{n+1}}{n(n + 1)} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left (\frac{H_{n + 1}}{n} - \frac{H_{n + 1}}{n + 1} \right ).\tag1 \label1$$

Now as the harmonic numbers satisfy the recurrence relation
$$H_{n + 1} = H_n + \frac{1}{n + 1},$$
we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_{n+1}}{n(n + 1)} &= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left [\frac{H_n}{n(n+1)} + \frac{1}{n(n +1)} - \frac{1}{(n + 1)^2} \right ]\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n(n + 1)} + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n + 1)} - \underbrace{\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n + 1)^2}}_{n \, \mapsto n - 1}\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n(n + 1)} + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)} - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} + 1\tag2\\
&= \zeta (2) + 1 - \zeta (2) + 1\\
&= 2
\end{align}
In (2) an evaluation for the first sum can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3063965/how-to-show-that-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nn2n-frac-pi26/3065775#3065775) while the second sum telescopes and has a sum equal to one.

Comment: just a little note. $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n} $ is divergent so we can not cancel these two sums. so we better simplify before distributing.

Comment: @Ali Shather Indeed you are absolutely right. Thanks and have corrected it now.

Comment: looks good now :)

Answer (score 2):

using the fact that $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^{n}\ln(1-x)\ dx=-\frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1}$

divide both sides by $-n$ then take the sum, 
\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n+1}}{n(n+1)}=-\int_0^1\ln(1-x)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}\right)\ dx\\
&=\int_0^1\ln^2(1-x)\ dx=\int_0^1\ln^2x\ dx=2
\end{align}